# Find point(s) of intersection between a line and a circle whose radius is parameterized by the same variable as the line

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, parametric

Let's assume we have a **line**:

$$\begin{align} 
x&: x_0 + v_xt, \\
y&: y_0 + v_yt \end{align}$$

and a **circle**

$$\begin{align}
x&: X_0 + kt\cos(s), \\
y&: Y_0 + kt\sin(s).\end{align}$$

Where does the line and the circle intersect?

Comment: Is your circle right? There are two variables $s$ and $t$. The image would be the whole plane, not only a circle.

Comment: @user251257 : this is OK. At a particular instant t there is a point (moving along the line) and a circle (with radius that keeps increasing). At which instants does the point lie on the circle.

Comment: An ugly solution: Solve the quadratic $(x_0 + v_x t - X_0)^2 + (y_0 + v_y t - Y_0)^2 = k^2 t^2$ for $t$.

Comment: @user251257 as I wrote in the title, the radius of the circle is depending on the same variable as the line is depending on. So technically yes, its image would be the whole plane.

Comment: @user251257 That is a mess! Is it really that hard?

Comment: at least better than solve for $t$ and $s$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Set $x_0+v_xt=X_0+kt\cos(s)$ and rearrange to make t the subject.

Set $y_0+v_yt=Y_0+kt\sin(s)$ and rearrange to make t the subject.

Make equal to each other and solve for s ... like this:

$x_0-X_0=kt\cos(s)-v_xt$

$t= \frac {x_0-X_0}{k\cos(s)-v_x}$

$y_0-Y_0=kt\sin(s)-v_yt$

$t= \frac {y_0-Y_0}{k\sin(s)-v_y}$

$\frac {x_0-X_0}{k\cos(s)-v_x}= \frac {y_0-Y_0}{k\sin(s)-v_y}$

$a \cos(s)-b\sin(s)=c$ where $a=k(y_0-Y_0)$ and $b=k(x_0-X_0)$ and $c=v_x(y_0-Y_0)-v_y(x_0-X_0)$

$rcos(s+\alpha)=c$ where $\alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac b a)$ and $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$s=\cos^{-1}(\frac c r)-\alpha$

Comment: http://imgur.com/wOmtmHi - does this look about correct?

Comment: That does look horrible! I'll take my answer a step forward...

Comment: I would appreciate that :)

Comment: $t = \frac{x_0 - X_0}{k\cos(s) - v_x}$ etc.

Comment: Oops - no difference made!

Comment: I would set $a=r\cos(s)$, $-b=r\sin(s)$, and follow $r = c$ and $s = \arctan(-b/a)$.

Comment: You get a circular argument that way: $s=\arctan(r \sin(s)/a)$

Comment: @tomi: no no, $a$ and $b$ are given. If I assume there are $r$ and $s$ such that $a=r\cos(s)$ and $-b=r\sin(s)$, then we have $a\cos(s) - b\sin(s) = r(\cos(s)^2 + \sin(s)^2) = c$. A possible choice for $r$ and $s$ would be $r=c$ and $s=\arctan(-b/a)$.

Comment: I didn't find this to be correct. The angle $s$ seems to be correct, but $t$ ends up as zero division all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: convert the cirlce to the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ and the line to $y=mx+b$.
substitute to the cirlce, this would lead a quadratic equation and we know how to solve!

Comment: Then I know that there is an intersection? Well, I guess there are two.

Comment: Doing this will give a line with no dependence on time and a circle with radius depending on time. There will be an infinite number of points of intersections but only some of them are valid in time.